# FullCalendar and Flot Resize Conflict

Tags: resize, fullcalendar, flot

I've successfully integrated both a Flot line graph and an instance of FullCalendar into my site. They are both on separate pages (although the pages are loaded into a div via AJAX).

I've added the Flot Resize plugin and that works perfectly, re-sizing the line graph as expected. However, it seems to cause an error when resizing the calendar.

Even if I load the calendar page first, when I resize the window I get this error in the console (also, the calendar does not resize correctly):

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'r.w=o!==c?o:q.width()')
```

I was struggling to work out where the error was coming from, so I removed the link to the Flot Resize JS and tried again. Of course the line graph does not resize, but when resizing the calendar, it works correctly.

The div containers for the two elements have different names and the resize function is called from within the function to draw the line graph (as required).

I have tried moving the link to the Flot Resize plugin into different places (i.e. above/below the fullCalendar JS, into the template which holds the graph), but all to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea where the conflict might be and how I might solve it??

Thanks very much!

EDIT: It seems that the error is also triggered when loading the line graph (flot) page AFTER the fullcalendar page even without resizing the window.... Now I am very confused!

EDIT 2: The code which draws the line graph. The function is called on pageload and recieves the data from JSON pulled off the server. When the graph is loaded, I still get the error about shutdown() being undefined.

```
function plotLineGraph(theData){
var myData = theData['data'];
var myEvents = theData['events'];
var myDates = theData['dates'];

var events = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<myEvents.length; i++) {
    events.push(
        {
            min: myEvents[i][0],
            max: myEvents[i][1],
            eventType: "Calendar Entry",
            title: myEvents[i][2],
            description:  myEvents[i][3]
        }

    );
}

  function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y + 5,
        left: x + 5,
        border: '1px solid #fdd',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': 'black',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}

 var previousPoint = null;
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
    $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

    if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length == 0) {
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                if(item.series.label != null){
                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                            item.series.label + " of " + y);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;            
        }
    }
});

var d1 = [
          myData[0],  myData[1],  myData[2],  myData[3],  myData[4],
          myData[5],  myData[6],  myData[7],  myData[8],  myData[9],
          myData[10], myData[11], myData[12], myData[13], myData[14],
          myData[15], myData[16], myData[17], myData[18], myData[19],
          myData[20], myData[21], myData[22], myData[23], myData[24],
          myData[25], myData[26], myData[27], myData[28], myData[29]
          ];
var markings = [
    { color: '#FFBDC1', yaxis: { from: 0, to: 2 } },
    { color: '#F2E2C7', yaxis: { from: 2, to: 3.5 } },
    { color: '#B6F2B7', yaxis: { from: 3.5, to: 5 } }
];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [
    {label: "Average Daily Rating", data: d1, color: "black"}
    ], {
        events: {
            data: events,
        },
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        },
        legend: { show: true, container: '#legend-holder' },
        xaxis: {
            ticks:[
            myDates[0],  myDates[1],  myDates[2],  myDates[3],  myDates[4],
            myDates[5],  myDates[6],  myDates[7],  myDates[8],  myDates[9],
            myDates[10], myDates[11], myDates[12], myDates[13], myDates[14],
            myDates[15], myDates[16], myDates[17], myDates[18], myDates[19],
            myDates[20], myDates[21], myDates[22], myDates[23], myDates[24],
            myDates[25], myDates[26], myDates[27], myDates[28], myDates[29]
            ],
        },
        yaxis: {
            ticks: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 5
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: { colors: ["#fff", "#eee"] },
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            markings: markings
        },
        selection: {
            color: 'white',
            mode: 'x'
        },
});
$('#placeholder').resize();
$('#placeholder').shutdown();
}
```

EDIT 3:

The calendar is called like this:

```
 function showCalendar() {
  var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    clickable: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/populate-calendar/{{theProductUuid}}/',
            color: 'black',
            data: {
                text: 'text'
            }
        }
    ],
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var startDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var endDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var eventId = calEvent.uuid;
        $('#modal-event-title').text(calEvent.title);
        $('#edit-event-name').val(calEvent.title);
        $('#edit-start-date').val(startDate);
        $('#edit-end-date').val(endDate);
        $('#edit-event-text').val(calEvent.text);
        $('#edit-event-btn').attr('data-uuid', eventId);
        $('#modal-edit-event').on('click', '#delete-btn', function(){
            deleteCalendarEvent(eventId);
        });
        $('#modal-edit-event').modal();
        },
});

}
```

The AJAX to load the page containing the flot chart:

```
function loadDetailedReports(uuid){
$('#product-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#product-content').empty();
    $('#whole-product-sub-nav .active').removeClass('active');
    $('#detailed-reports-content').load('/detailed-reports/' + uuid + '/', function(){
        $('#detailed-reports-btn').addClass('active');
        $('#detailed-reports-content').fadeIn('slow', function(){
            if (authorized){
                setLocationHash('loadDetailedReports&' + uuid);
                getChartData(uuid);
            } else {
            setLocationHash('');
            }
        });
    });
});
}
```

And the AJAX to load the page containing the calendar:

```
function loadCalendar(uuid){
$('#detailed-reports-content').empty().hide();
$('#product-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#whole-product-sub-nav .active').removeClass('active');
    $('#product-content').load('/calendar/' + uuid + '/', function(){
        $('#calendar-btn').addClass('active');
        $('#product-content').fadeIn('slow', function(){
            if (authorized){
                setLocationHash('loadCalendar&' + uuid);
            } else {
                setLocationHash('');
            }
            showCalendar();
        });
    });
});
}
```

The calls to .resize and .shutdown are there because I was under the impression that they are necessary to achieve the resizing function and in response to your earlier comment regarding shutdown...... They're quite possibly n00b errors........?!?!

Comment: Flot resize includes an inline copy of Ben Alman's jquery-resize plugin.  It sounds like there's a conflict between that and whatever the calendar is using, since we haven't received any other reports of resize producing this kind of error.  How is the calendar doing its resizing?

Comment: Automagically......! FullCalendar seems to have built-in resizing functionality. A quick search through the JS file reveals a windowResize function within fullcalendar.js

Comment: Okay, so it's not using another copy of jquery-resize or anything.  Where exactly does that error come up?  Is it in flot.js, flot.resize.js, or elsewhere?  What line number?

Comment: To confirm: the easiest way for me to replicate the behaviour is to load the page with the flot graph (via AJAX), then load the page with the calendar (again via AJAX, into the same div after 'unloading' the graph content), then go back to the graph's page. I always get the error as above. Console doesn't give me a line number, but searching for that string gives me line 22 in flot.resize.js. (and nothing in flot.js).

Comment: I should add that I get the same error when trying to resize the calendar.

Comment: Where's the calendar and AJAX?  What's the goal of the resize & shutdown calls at the end of the function?

Comment: Added the code to the question!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is triggering on line 198 of jquery-resize:

```
data.w = w !== undefined ? w : elem.width();
```

This sounds like a race-condition stemming from the way you load different content into the same div.  Flot binds the resize event to the chart div, and only un-binds it if the plot is destroyed cleanly.

EDIT: Looking at your code, my first suggestion would be to get rid of the resize and shutdown calls at the end of plotLineGraph.  The resize plugin doesn't require any setup; it hooks into Flot to attach automatically to any new plot.  So your call to resize is actually to jQuery's resize event trigger, which may be what's causing the error.

EDIT #2: I'm still not clear on your structure, but to generalize: anywhere that you might be getting rid of #placeholder (via emptying its parent or anything like that) you should first call shutdown on the plot object.  If you aren't keeping a reference to it, you can do it like this: `$("#placeholder").data("plot").shutdown();` but then have to account for the fact that it's undefined prior to the creation of your first plot.

If that still doesn't work, I'd need to see a live (simplified) example to make any further suggestions.

Comment: Thanks DNS - I'll try loading into different divs first, then come back.

Comment: OK, I think this is the problem (that the chart div is not being destroyed cleanly), but can you suggest the simplest way to destroy it cleanly? Would calling `.empty()` on the containing div (i.e. `#placeholder.parent()` work? Or does it need a more 'substantial' destruction....?

Comment: Calling shutdown() on the plot object before you empty or get rid of it should do the trick.

Comment: OK, now I'm struggling with `.shutdown()`. I try to use it like this: `$('#placeholder').shutdown();`, and I get this error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#placeholder').shutdown()')`..... Clearly I'm not calling it correctly, but I can't find any examples of the correct syntax...... I'm also trying to think of a good way to call shutdown when the user navigates away from the page (bearing in mind the AJAX nature of the site, `.unload()` doesn't work).

Comment: I've tried loading the Flot chart and the calendar into entirely separate divs and sticking the flot.resize script into the chart's div.... Have also called .empty() when leaving the chart's page, all to avail. The only thing I can't get working is the .shutdown() method..... If you can give me an example as to how to get that working, that would be great! Otherwise, I'll have to ditch the resize plugin....

Comment: You need to call it on the plot object; the return value of calling .plot().  You don't need to call it on page unload, since the whole thing is going away anyway.  At this point there's nothing else I can suggest without seeing your code, or ideally a stripped-down example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks DNS. I tried removing the calls to resize and shutdown: removing the resize call results in the events plugin not positioning the events indicators properly until after a resize occurs. This may just need a minor refactor to fix, but either way, I still get the error, so that's not the solution unfortunately. `#placeholder` is within a few parent divs (widget-boxes etc) - the whole content of the page is loaded into `#detailed-reports-content`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help DNS - unfortunately nothing is working.... I've tried all your suggestions, but nothing seems to work. The code in your second edit for shutting down the plot returns undefined when I run it in the console...? Unfortunately, I can't really post any more of the code than I already have, so I've had to remove the resize plugin for now.